# How to make visible the shadow between the two columns?

Tags: html, css, padding

I have two columns with blurred shadow, but after float the shadow between the columns is not visible. I use border-box, but it does not work. How to solve this problem?

```css
.column {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  border-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

h3,
h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
}

.over1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.more:link {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:blue;">
    <div>
      <h3>A selyemút tükrében</h3>
    </div>
    <img class="contain" src="selyemut.jpg" style="width:100%;height:200px">
    <div>
      <h5 style="color: white;">Fotókiállítás megnyitó ünnepség a Múzeumportán</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="over1">
      <p style="color:white;">A Kínából érkező Wei Xiang, valamint Szamódy Zsolt Olaf, Á. Tóth József és több magyar fotográfus képeiből készült kiállítást nyitották meg Cigándon, a Bodrogközi Múzeumportán 2018. június 27-én.A Selyemút hajdan összekötötte Kínát és a Világot,
        de a sok ezer kilométeres út mentén élő népek, népcsoportok mindennapjairól, kultúrájáról, napi történéseiről szinte semmit nem tudtak az emberek, lehettek akár kínaiak, akár európaiak.A hazai fotográfusok viszont felismerték ezt a hiányosságot
        és a Magyar Fotóművészek Szövetsége tagjai évekkel ezelőtt elkezdtek megismerkedni Kínával.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="more">>> Bővebben...</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:blue;">
    <div>
      <h3>A selyemút tükrében</h3>
    </div>
    <img class="contain" src="selyemut.jpg" style="width:100%;height:200px">
    <div>
      <h5 style="color: white;">Fotókiállítás megnyitó ünnepség a Múzeumportán</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="over1">
      <p style="color:white;">A Kínából érkező Wei Xiang, valamint Szamódy Zsolt Olaf, Á. Tóth József és több magyar fotográfus képeiből készült kiállítást nyitották meg Cigándon, a Bodrogközi Múzeumportán 2018. június 27-én.A Selyemút hajdan összekötötte Kínát és a Világot,
        de a sok ezer kilométeres út mentén élő népek, népcsoportok mindennapjairól, kultúrájáról, napi történéseiről szinte semmit nem tudtak az emberek, lehettek akár kínaiak, akár európaiak.A hazai fotográfusok viszont felismerték ezt a hiányosságot
        és a Magyar Fotóművészek Szövetsége tagjai évekkel ezelőtt elkezdtek megismerkedni Kínával.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="more">>> Bővebben...</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a right margin to your columns:

```css
.column {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  border-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

h3,
h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
}

.over1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.more:link {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:blue;">
    <div>
      <h3>A selyemút tükrében</h3>
    </div>
    <img class="contain" src="selyemut.jpg" style="width:100%;height:200px">
    <div>
      <h5 style="color: white;">Fotókiállítás megnyitó ünnepség a Múzeumportán</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="over1">
      <p style="color:white;">A Kínából érkező Wei Xiang, valamint Szamódy Zsolt Olaf, Á. Tóth József és több magyar fotográfus képeiből készült kiállítást nyitották meg Cigándon, a Bodrogközi Múzeumportán 2018. június 27-én.A Selyemút hajdan összekötötte Kínát és a Világot,
        de a sok ezer kilométeres út mentén élő népek, népcsoportok mindennapjairól, kultúrájáról, napi történéseiről szinte semmit nem tudtak az emberek, lehettek akár kínaiak, akár európaiak.A hazai fotográfusok viszont felismerték ezt a hiányosságot
        és a Magyar Fotóművészek Szövetsége tagjai évekkel ezelőtt elkezdtek megismerkedni Kínával.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="more">>> Bővebben...</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:blue;">
    <div>
      <h3>A selyemút tükrében</h3>
    </div>
    <img class="contain" src="selyemut.jpg" style="width:100%;height:200px">
    <div>
      <h5 style="color: white;">Fotókiállítás megnyitó ünnepség a Múzeumportán</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="over1">
      <p style="color:white;">A Kínából érkező Wei Xiang, valamint Szamódy Zsolt Olaf, Á. Tóth József és több magyar fotográfus képeiből készült kiállítást nyitották meg Cigándon, a Bodrogközi Múzeumportán 2018. június 27-én.A Selyemút hajdan összekötötte Kínát és a Világot,
        de a sok ezer kilométeres út mentén élő népek, népcsoportok mindennapjairól, kultúrájáról, napi történéseiről szinte semmit nem tudtak az emberek, lehettek akár kínaiak, akár európaiak.A hazai fotográfusok viszont felismerték ezt a hiányosságot
        és a Magyar Fotóművészek Szövetsége tagjai évekkel ezelőtt elkezdtek megismerkedni Kínával.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="more">>> Bővebben...</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **margin-right** to shift the columns from each other.

```
.column { 
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Suggestion:** Don't do both inline and internal/external styling. Try to avoid it and put all your styles in one place. It will be easy for you to review and make changes as well in the future.

Comment: How is your answer any different from mine which was posted three hours earlier?

Comment: @j08691 Sir, you sure did answer first. I just wanted to point out the fact to the person who asked the question that it is not a good practice to do both inline and external styling for the same component.

Comment: That would probably have best been left as a comment

Comment: I was hoping to do the same but until a few moments ago I didn't have enough reps to comment on a post.